# How does $1/f$ come out as the intercept when plotting a graph of $1/u$ and $1/v$ in convex lens?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

On [this link](http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Optics/Refraction/text/Lenses_focal_length_measurement/index.html), in the convex lens second method to calculate focal length. I did not understand how the graph of 1/u and 1/v can give 1/f as the intercept? Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac1u+\frac1v=\frac1f$, where $f$ is some constant property of the lens. Let $y=1/u$, and $x=1/v$. Then $y=1/f − x$, which is the equation of a straight line, gradient $-1$ and $y$-intercept $1/f$. Setting $y=0$, we can get the $x$-intercept which it turns out is also $1/f$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the quantities 1/p and 1/q are always constant for one lens and equal to 1/f.
Thus the graph represents a straight line with a negative slope. Imagine the sum x and y components for every point on the line: they add up to a constant value.

[image: This is the graph of 1/q or 1/i Vs. 1/p or 1/o Vs.]